# App crash while retrieve event with Identifier from calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

When user delete the event manually from the calendar and app try to retrieve that EKEvent with identifier from EKEventStore then app is getting crash with the below error.

> *Error getting event with identifier AB78AC19-BD17-4290-8A21-4BF948089C12:66F6F5BC-BF61-401A-B808-44A555F7E63E:
>   Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1010.)" fatal error: unexpectedly
>   found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Here is the code use to fetch event with identifier

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let event = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: identifier as String)!
```

Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if event exists:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
if let event = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: identifier as String) {
    //do what you need with the event
}
```